# "EconSpark": The AEA's new forum

Tags: discussion

Just wanted to draw people's attention on "EconSpark", the AEA's new: https://www.aeaweb.org/economics-discussion-forum.

Although there might be some overlap, I believe EconSpark and EconSE are mostly complementary.

Comment: seems interesting, I made an account but only am able to view stuff till an admin approves. seems cool

Comment: On a cursory glance, I am mostly wondering what the scope of questions is that can be asked on that website.